# Convert CSV to multi dimensional array in Javascript

Tags: jquery, arrays, csv

I'm reading data from a CSV file using jQuery's Ajax function. I have been using a Jquery plugin called [Jquery CSV](http://js-tables.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.csv.min.js) to convert the data into an array, but in Internet Explorer the array is returning different keys for some reason.

The code for the ajax call and the plugin processing the data was:

```
var ourOffices = new Array();
$.get(pathToData, function(data) {
   ourOffices = jQuery.csv("|")(data);
});
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to coding this conversion without a plug in.

The fields are separated by '|' . Each record is on a new line, of which there are 300. Also of note, which might be why the first plugin misbehaves, is that some of the data in the CSV contain special characters, like accents.

Thanks.

p.s. I would supply some example data, but its not appropriate to do so, sorry.

Comment: do u have a more readable version of your plugin. Javascript code pls too.

Comment: Source for the plugin is here. http://js-tables.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.csv.js

Comment: JS above, its nothing special at that stage as the plugin is doing the grunt.

Comment: I'm sure you have seen the comment in the plugin `split() doesn't work properly on IE. "a,,b".split(",") returns ["a", "b"] and not ["a", "", "b"]` could that be your issue.

Comment: Oh man, I feel like a fool, no I just rushed in and grabbed the minified version. But it looks like the plugin is testing for the failure, no?

Comment: follow the link the plug gives. It looks like there is a fix. Of course if your CSV as empty fields.

Comment: Happy days, that was indeed the problem, if you want to whack this an answer millebii I'll accept and upvote :)

Comment: It doesn't answer your question but if you want a working CSV parsing lib that is completely RFC 4801 compliant, take a look at the link in my profile. Technically, null values *should* be valid, it's the implementation you're using that's incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you have seen the comment in the plugin split() doesn't work properly on IE. "a,,b".split(",") returns ["a", "b"] and not ["a", "", "b"] could that be your issue.