# csv to multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I'm far from good at javascript. I'm cobbling together a page to analyze a *csv file* and created a page with results.

So I'm using papaparse.js for csv parsing and the stepFn to process each line, to eliminate records using various selection criteria.
I've also included **moment.js** to handle dates and times.

so there's 3 pieces of data I want to work with. (I'm simplifying).
[fundraising] team, amount, and date (which I'll store as a unix time integer).

I've been trying to see if outdata[teamname] exists, and if it does, update the amount. And if the amount >= goalamount, then populate date (if it's not already populated).

basically my web page allows them to define selection criteria, a goal, and to choose whether the challenge was [who gets their first]/sort on date, or [who got the most] sort on amount. [where total can actually be a count or

if the team isn't in the outdata array, add it, and place in it the total and a date (which of course I have to check for goal-reaching).

I've tried

```
var exists = typeof outdata[thisteamname];
if (exists == undefined)
{
    outdata.push({ team: thisteamname, total: usevalue, adate: 0 });
}
else
{
    var z = outdata[thisteamname]['total'];
    //---->>> Cannot read property 'total' of undefined

    outdata[thisteamname]['total'] += usevalue;
}
```

etc .. but  i think I'm going about it all wrong. Suggestions? I will also need to sort the outdata array by eithe date or total, and loop through it for a top-ten style list at the end to write html.

all help appreciated, I know my javascript looks rather BASICy.

Comment: For one, sorry, I didn't paste the code in, I wrote it from scratch here, presume the syntax errors at least aren't in the actual code.

Comment: Then please correct your post

Comment: currently getting a problem with team in the 8th line as seen above, and I think I see part of the issue. Does the outdata.push I'm using set up thisteamname as the 'key' to access the data in the array because it's first? Because when I go to set z, I'm just passing thisteamname, and not saying it's in the "team"? Confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert CSV to multi dimensional array in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230717/convert-csv-to-multi-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

Comment: I am not using jquery. It may make my code easier, but it would be something additional to learn on top of cobbling this together and figuring out the papaparse.js and moment.js libraries.

Comment: you've confused arrays and objects.  `push` is for appending to an array, for adding a key-value pairing to an object you just do `outdata[thisteamname]={total:usevalue,adata:0}`

Comment: @dan-man, so I can use if (thisteamname in outdata) to see if it's there, how do I adata's current value if it is, and how do I change it? And that statement above adds thisteamname to the array, or do I first need to push it on?

Comment: these are basic questions about the language. i think they are best answered by googling for introduction/reference on objects and arrays